# Karma Chrome Headless not working on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, docker, jenkins, karma-runner

When I run the below setup with Docker locally on my mac everything works fine.

But same setup does not work on Jenkins running on Ubuntu 16.04

**ChromiumHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.**

Following error log is from **Jenkins console:**

```
25 05 2018 06:35:09.076:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.2 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9222/
25 05 2018 06:35:09.079:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chromium_no_sandbox with unlimited concurrency
25 05 2018 06:35:09.090:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromiumHeadless
25 05 2018 06:36:09.128:WARN [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
25 05 2018 06:36:09.139:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromiumHeadless again (1/2).
25 05 2018 06:37:09.140:WARN [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
25 05 2018 06:37:09.147:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromiumHeadless again (2/2).
```

**Package.json** ...
`"testProd": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf-prod.js --single-run",`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM zenika/alpine-node:latest
LABEL name="product-web"

# Update apk repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install chromium
RUN apk -U --no-cache \
    --allow-untrusted add \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    xvfb \
    wait4ports \
    xorg-server \
    dbus \
    ttf-freefont \
    mesa-dri-swrast \
    grep \
    udev \
    && apk del --purge --force linux-headers binutils-gold gnupg zlib-dev libc-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/* \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/doc \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/html \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/scripts

WORKDIR /home/dev/code
COPY . .

#RUN rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clear --force

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
ENV CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/

RUN npm install
RUN npm run testProd && npm run buildProd
```

**karma.conf-prod.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-test-profile',
                '--disable-web-security'
            ]
        }
    },
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        captureConsole: true,
        files: [
            'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
            'test/root.js'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'src/index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'test/root.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                        query: {
                            plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-regenerator'],
                            presets: ['env', 'stage-1', 'react']
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.json$/,
                        loader: 'json-loader',
                    },
                ]
            },
            externals: {
                'react/addons': true,
                'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
                'react/lib/ReactContext': true
            }
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        },
        reporters: ['spec'],
        port: 9222,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO
    });
};
```

I even tried with `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` but did not show anything missing or unusual.

Comment: I was able to solve this using Travic CI `before_install:
 - export DISPLAY=:99.0
 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
 - sleep 3`

Comment: If you needed xvfb that means you are not running headless at all

Comment: @TarunLalwani I maybe wrong, but I have added headless config in Karma. `base: ChromeHeadless `

Comment: I can see that, but may be the browser is crashing with some error, so possibly we need to get output of that process

Comment: Im not sure how do I get the log for chrome crash. Can you point me in the direction ! [please note] we have decided on team's to move to Travic-CI, since the ease of use and less bugs

Comment: Is this a public git project?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no, its private git repo. But the config can be used anywhere, thats all you would need if you had to reproduce. Let me know if you want `webpack.config`

Comment: Can you create a minimal public repo with travis config as well? Then I can debug from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172433/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-steel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the jenkin's `xbmc` display driver .

I fixed it by switching to Travic-CI

```
before_install: - export DISPLAY=:99.0 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start - sleep 3
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on [issue Karma 1.6 breaks Headless support for Chrome](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652) created on [github](https://github.com/), it is related to the slower machine and happens, because it took > 60 seconds before test bundle was parsed and executed by Chrome and therefore test run was started and communicated back to Karma server. Reasons why it may take long vary.

There are 2 ways to handle timeout:

Investigate why your test bundle loads >60 seconds and make sure it loads faster.

1. Increase [browserNoActivityTimeout](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) to highter value, so test bundle
   has enough time to load.
2. This particular appearance of timeout does not seem to be a Karma
   issue, but rather problem in the project or misconfiguration.

Based on the [Derek's](https://github.com/daryl0313) comment

There was a connection that was disconnecting too soon.

He found that in /static/karma.js, when the socket was created, there was a timeout value that is hardcoded to 2 seconds (see below). He just added another 0 to make it 20 seconds and the connection stayed open long enough for the server to respond to the initial request.
karma/client/main.js

Lines 14 to 20 in e79463b

```
var socket = io(location.host, { 
   reconnectionDelay: 500, 
   reconnectionDelayMax: Infinity, 
   timeout: 2000, 
   path: KARMA_PROXY_PATH + KARMA_URL_ROOT.substr(1) + 'socket.io', 
   'sync disconnect on unload': true 
 })
```

The next problem he faced was that Karma thought there was no activity even though there was traffic going back and forth on the socket. To fix that he just added browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000 to the Karma configuration.

You need to change the timeout configuration more then that is in the configuration file.

Comment: As per OP, it works with XVFB, which particularly indicates that the browser may be crashing in headless mode. So I think it may not be related to browser being slow in launch. If it is slow in launch, it would be slow under XVFB also

Comment: @Kiran Shahi thanks for answer. But the same karma config works fine with Travis CI.

TarunLalwani thanks

Comment: `browserNoActivityTimeout ` I have played with this property with no luck, forgot to mention.

Comment: To change the timeout for capturing you can set explicitly `captureTimeout` in karma.conf.js. However, more commonly it is a problem with the proxies and NO_PROXY parameter.

Comment: Adding my +1; This fixed it for me

Answer (score 6):

package.json

```
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
```

karma.conf.js

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
    ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
},
```

and need to use the below command with --source-map=false

```
"qa-test": "ng test --watch=false --progress=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage --source-map=false"
```

**my build got succeeded after this change.**

Comment: This should be the answer definitely.  7/20/20  I'll add also that this does not work with npm run tests though.

Answer (score 4):

had the same issue "**ChromHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms**" (failing after 3 attempts), on **Jenkins** running on **RHEL 7.5**. Tried several configurations, and eventually adding the **--proxy-bypass-list**, and **--proxy-server** made it work.

**minimal working configuration**

```
 browsers: ['HeadlessChrome'],
    customLaunchers:{
      HeadlessChrome:{
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
          '--proxy-server=\'http://<my org proxy server>:8080\''
       ]
      }
    },
```

Below you can see a few more options in the config like the one I used. We have two browser configuration, Chrome for day to day dev work where we do want to see the browser open, and a headless chrome for CI/CD tests when building our solution on a Jenkins server.

Command line to run it in Jenkins:

```
npm run test -- -cc -sr --browser HeadlessChrome
```

In **package.json** we added a couple of lines to the **scripts** section:

```
 "test": "ng test",
    "test-dev": "ng test --browser Chrome",
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
 browsers: ['Chrome', 'HeadlessChrome'],
    customLaunchers:{
      HeadlessChrome:{
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
       //   '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
       //   '--enable-logging',
       //   '--user-data-dir=./karma-chrome',
       //   '--v=1',
       //   '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
       //   '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
          '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
          '--proxy-server=\'http://<my org proxy server>:8080\''
       ]
      }
    },
```

After the above steps it worked from a shell on the Jenkins machine. However it failed when running as a Jenkins job with **Cannot start ChromeHeadless   Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (1/2).** printed to the console.

I compared the env variables, and after a few trial and errors found that **XDG_DATA_DIRS** environment variable exists when logged in a bash shell (where headless chrome tests succeeds), and this variable was not defined in the failing Jenkins job env. So adding it (copied from the shell **env | grep XDG_DATA_DIRS**) finally solved it. I guess I should check what is the minimal configuration/dirs I should put there, and what is the root cause, but its working now :-)

**Added the below to the jenkins job just before running the test**

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/users/<jenkins user e.g. jk1003>/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

**Another possible solution**

A friend told me that he solved such an issue long ago using [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

Answer (score 3):

For me, below worked, seems version and conf issue:

In **package.json**
I am using:

```
"karma": "1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0"
```

In **karma conf** add this:

```
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    }
```

It shall work.

Comment: ChromeHeadless can't run as root with --no-sandbox. Facing this error

Answer (score 2):

For me I have to add the chrome local ip/port explicitly to `NO_PROXY` so that `Karma` could capture the browser.

In the `karma.conf.js`:

```
process.env.NO_PROXY = 'localhost, 0.0.0.0/4201, 0.0.0.0/9876';
process.env.no_proxy = 'localhost, 0.0.0.0/4201, 0.0.0.0/9876';
```

Note, even I export it in our `jenkinsfile`, it does not work, Have to be in the js process.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue on Jenkins 2 with `ChromeHeadless/ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox`.

Setting `captureTimeout` in karma.ci.conf.js(in my case) as well as adding `--no-proxy-server` flag worked for me.

```
  customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox','--no-proxy-server']
               }
            },
    captureTimeout: 180000
```

Comment: `captureTimeout` was definitely what was causing my Jenkins woes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the machine was out of disk space, specifically for the /tmp/ folder.

Once I fixed that, the Jenkins job is able to run successfully again.